Import a text file as a string in a Jest test in an Angular project
I'm trying to import a text file as a string to inject some data for testing.
import rawStr from '../../testdata/testdata.txt';

This fails:
$ npm test

> angular@0.0.0 test
> ng test

NOTE: The Jest builder is currently EXPERIMENTAL and not ready for production use.
Application bundle generation failed. [2.806 seconds]

✘ [ERROR] TS2307: Cannot find module '../../testdata/testdata.txt' or its corresponding type declarations. [plugin angular-compiler]

    src/util/diff.component.spec.ts:6:22:
      6 │ import rawStr from '../../testdata/testdata.txt';
        ╵                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

How can I tell the Angular compiler (or maybe the Jest compiler?) that we should import the contents of the file as a string?
angular.json:
{
    "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
    "version": 1,
    "newProjectRoot": "projects",
    "projects": {
        "angular": {
            "projectType": "application",
            "root": "",
            "sourceRoot": "src",
            "architect": {
                "build": {
                    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:application",
                    "options": {
                        "outputPath": "dist/angular",
                        "index": "src/index.html",
                        "browser": "src/main.ts",
                        "polyfills": [],
                        "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
                        "assets": [
                            "src/favicon.ico",
                            "src/assets"
                        ],
                        "styles": [
                            "src/styles.css",
                            "node_modules/@fontsource/roboto/300.css",
                            "node_modules/@fontsource/roboto/400.css",
                            "node_modules/@fontsource/roboto/500.css",
                            "node_modules/@fontsource/material-icons/400.css",
                            "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css",
                            "node_modules/bootstrap-icons/font/bootstrap-icons.css"
                        ],
                        "scripts": [
                            "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"
                        ]
                    },
                    "configurations": {
                        "production": {
                            "outputHashing": "all"
                        },
                        "development": {
                            "optimization": false,
                            "extractLicenses": false,
                            "sourceMap": true
                        }
                    },
                    "defaultConfiguration": "production"
                },
                "serve": {
                    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
                    "configurations": {
                        "production": {
                            "buildTarget": "angular:build:production"
                        },
                        "development": {
                            "buildTarget": "angular:build:development"
                        }
                    },
                    "defaultConfiguration": "development"
                },
                "extract-i18n": {
                    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
                    "options": {
                        "buildTarget": "angular:build"
                    }
                },
                "test": {
                    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:jest",
                    "options": {
                        "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

I'm using jest@29.7.0 and angular/cli@18.2.3.

Have you considered not importing it? Use Node's fs to load it.

@jonrsharpe: That fails with The package "fs" wasn't found on the file system but is built into node. Are you trying to bundle for node? You can use "platform: 'node'" to do that, which will remove this error.. It is entirely unobvious to me (including with searching around) on where I should specify platform: node to resolve this.
